# How can i address this---> Error HTTP Status 404 on my Code below

Tags: java, html, xml, tomcat

So i'm trying to display info in the web using servlets and i am stuck, I have tried searching and researching but with vain, i have found no help.I was wondering could it be an issues with the server? It keeps giving me this error `HTTP Status 404` when i try to run my html with the dopost method in Java. Otherwise when i run my Java class on my server it displays without any issues , also when i run my html on the web it displays without any issue but `CANNOT` get the method. Please any help will be appreciated. My codes are as follows.. /i am getting the same error with my `.JSP` file too. This are just examples i have decided to use so as to solve my issue with my main code.

My Java Code

```
package helloServelets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LearningServelets
 */
@WebServlet("/LearningServelets")
public class LearningServelets extends HttpServlet {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String yourname = request.getParameter("YourName");
    String enter = request.getParameter("Enter");
    String school = request.getParameter("SchoolName");
    String work = request.getParameter("Work");
    String Home = request.getParameter("home");


        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter output = response.getWriter();

        output.println("<html><body><h3>Hello " + yourname);

        output.println("</h3><br />" + enter + " + " + school+work);
        output.println(Home + "<br /> "  + "</body></html>");

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
    }

}
```

My HTML code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="LearningServelets">

What is your YourName?
<input name = "Yourname"> 
<p>
What is your Gender

<input name ="Enter">
</p>
<p>
Where did you go to school?
<input name = "SchoolName">
</p>

<p>
Where do you Work?
<input name = "Work">
</p>

<p>
Where do you live?
<input name = "home">
</p>
<input type ="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And my XML file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ServeletsLearning</display-name>
      <servlet> 
     <servlet-name>LearningServelets</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>helloServelets.LearningServelets</servlet-class>
     </servlet>

</web-app>
```

Comment: 404 is an http error which is from the helloServelets.  The title of your posting is misleading because the issue has nothing to do with the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="LearningServlet">

        What is your age?<input name = "age"><br> 
        What is your Gender?<input name ="gender"><br>
        Where did you go to school?<input name = "schoolname"><br>          
        Where do you Work?<input name = "work"><br>
        Where do you live?<input name = "home"><br>
        <input type ="submit">
    </form> 
</body>
```

LearningServlet.java File
    package helloservlet;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/LearningServlet")
public class LearningServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public LearningServlet() {
    super();
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String age=request.getParameter("age");
    String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
    String schoolname=request.getParameter("schoolName");
    String work=request.getParameter("work");
    String home=request.getParameter("home");

    response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType("text/html"));
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    pw.write("<html><body>");
    pw.write("Age           :"+age+"<br>");
    pw.write("Gender        :"+gender+"<br>");
    pw.write("School Name   :"+schoolname+"<br>");
    pw.write("Work          :"+work+"<br>");
    pw.write("Home          :"+home+"<br>");
    pw.write("</body></html>");
   }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>helloservlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Now Deploy your Project on the server and open in browser:
    http://localhost:8080/helloservlet/index.html

NOTE:assuming your application/project name is helloservlet

Comment: You mean i remove everything in XML? and i remain with <display-name>ServeletsLearning</display-name>? you can try posting the removed code i will appreciate

Comment: Huh am stranded and want to move on.. This is stressing me.

Comment: i have edited my answer. make required changes or just copy paste the code. let us know if it works for you. Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks let me check it out. :)